# Magento 2: Use Google API client library for PHP

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, google-api

I want to use Google API client library for PHP in my extension to upload YouTube video. I ran following composer command to add this library.

```
composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
```

But I got following error...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key is the last line. The package requires monolog in at least version 1.17, but it is currently **locked** at 1.16, because Magento installed it too.

You should be able to process in two steps:

1. require the package but do not install immediately:

   ```
   composer require --no-update google/apiclient:~2.0
   ```
2. update it together with monolog:

   ```
   composer update google/apiclient monolog/monolog
   ```

Comment: I tried it but it is not working.

Comment: I see that in Magento 2.0 and 2.1 monolog was required exactly in version `1.16`, so it would be incompatible with `google/apiclient`. It has changed here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/9ca160f56c4f3cde51267251f57f30a1c4da03aa but you will have to wait for the 2.2 release, or try to edit your project's composer.json to change the monolog version requirement

Comment: Which composer.json ? Can you give me file location ?

Comment: `/var/www/html/Magento216/composer.json`

Comment: Alternatively run `composer require monolog/monolog:^1.17`

Comment: I tried it too. Still not working.

Comment: If you update your question with what exactly you tried and what the results were, I might be able to help you.

Comment: Basically I want to upload video in youtube using Magento2 extension. Can you guide me for the same ?